# CPU features and compiler symbols

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, cpu, symbols

I have a question about how compiler-set symbols, in particular CPU feature flags (like SSE, AES, AVX) are actually set. For instance, if I call gcc with -mavx, is the `__AVX__` symbol set *regardless* of whether the system the code is about to be built on actually supports AVX instructions, or does it check before?

I'm asking because I need to build a particular code path depending on CPU capabilities and would like to automate it so that the correct path is determined upon compilation based on the build system, instead of manually enabling desired features. But since the only CPU I have supports basically every feature, I cannot test my above assumption (first world problems, I know)

There is going to be *a lot* of code so simply keeping everything and branching at runtime is unacceptable - and it is assumed that my library will be built before being used on a given system anyway.

I mean, at worst I can force this behavior by wrapping the gcc arguments in a cpuid-aware script, but if gcc does it automatically it would be preferable. So does anyone know whether it does?

---

I am mostly interested in gcc's take on this but I am also curious to know how other C compilers behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the `-mavx` flag, `__AVX__` will *always* be set for the resulting compilation (and the resulting code may not run on non-AVX machines).

If you pass the `-march=native` flag, gcc will enable the instruction sets supported by the build machine, so `__AVX__` will only be set if the build machine supports it.

Comment: Ah, great, so I can just use '-march=native' and symbols for all supported features will be set automatically, very neat. I will read up on this flag, thanks!

Comment: To explain why the compiler behaves this way: Switches such as “-mavx” tell the compiler what the **target** machine will be, and the compiler sets preprocessor symbols to match that, so that source code can use those symbols to adjust for the target machine. The machine you build on might have no relationship to the target machine; it is simply a general computing device that is turning C source code into executable code for the target machine. It is only because we so often use a compiler to compile for the current machine that we think of the current machine as what the compiler is set for.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. I agree that it is not really intuitive, especially since in Linux for instance you seldom hand binaries out, so usually when you compile something it's to run it on the system it was compiled. But it is more flexible and logical this way.